# How to create a Browse button in android to load any directory from sdcard or internal card?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, directory, cordova-plugins

I want a button which browses directory path so that in my app I will be able to browse the any folder in android whether it is in the internal storage or external storage
So that with the help of that folder I can play videos.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be you should check this http://sampleprogramz.com/android/browse.php

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to browse directory in android and pick files.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btn;
    int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE){
            Log.d("TAG", "File Uri " +data.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I already add the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml. But where I have to put the above code

Comment: Did you know basics of android??

Comment: Yeah of course, but I don't write any JAVA Code but I write js code so that's why I am asking where I have to put this code as this is a Pure Java Code

Comment: are you developing on android studio or any other cross platform tool ???

Comment: No I am not developing n Android Studio . I am using cordova

Comment: I am not familiar with cardova but i thinks this would help 

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: Also have a look at this http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/17/list-android-directory-in-cordova